# Need help merging 2 HQL queries

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I just can't figure out how to optimize this into one query in HQL.  Currently, I have the following 2 HQL queries.  They both return the results that I want and I can merge those results in C# and do what I need to.  However, there must be some way to just generate a single query to return all of the results.  Everything I've tried so far either just generates an error or gives me the intersection of the 2 result sets.  I'm sure I'm just missing something small.  Thanks.

```
SELECT u FROM UserImpl u INNER JOIN u.Friends f WHERE f.State = :state AND f.Gender = :gender
SELECT u FROM UserImpl u INNER JOIN u.Relatives r WHERE r.State = :state AND r.Gender = :gender
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, I think:

```
SELECT u FROM UserImpl u 
LEFT JOIN u.Friends f 
LEFT JOIN u.Relatives r 
WHERE f.State = :state 
AND (f.Gender = :gender OR r.Gender = :gender)
```

Comment: perfect.  i must've tried every combination except, somehow, this. thanks!